# How to pass 2 arguments lambda as function argument ? Destructuring declarations initializer of type String must have a 'component1()' function

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I have a function:

```
fun foo(arg1: Int, arg2: String, lambda: (String, Int) -> Int): Int {
    return arg1 + arg2.length + lambda("123", 1)
}
```

Nw I want to call it and do following:

```
fun bar() {
    foo(1, "2") { (a, b) -> 42 }
}
```

But it tends to compile error:

```
Expected 2 parameters of types String, Int
Destructuring declarations initializer of type String must have a 'component1()' function
```

I also tried explicitly use types

```
fun bar() {
    foo(1, "2") { (a:String, b:Int) -> 42 }
}
```

but still compile error:

```
required (String,Int) -> Int
but found: (String) -> Int
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have the parenthesis in `(a, b)`, if I remember the syntax correctly.

Comment: Oh, you rescued me

Comment: `{ (a, b) -> 42 }` is a lambda that takes _a single parameter_, which you have destructured and called `(a, b)`. On the other hand, `{ a, b -> 42 }` is a lambda that takes _two parameters_, `a` and `b`. Also, in your function declaration `fun foo(arg1: Int, arg2: String, lambda: (String, Int) -> Int)`, the parameter `lambda` is actually **not a lambda** and shouldn't be called that. The lambda is a literal expression of function type. If you had a function taking a String parameter, you wouldn't call the parameter "stringLiteral". Function-type arguments are typically called `block`.

Comment: @k314159 That's certainly enough info to deserve a full answer!  I encourage you to post it as one.

Comment: @k314159 thank you. Please add the answer but didn't get your point about stringLiteral

Comment: I've added an answer that hopefully clarifies what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ (a, b) -> 42 }` is a lambda that takes a single parameter, which you have destructured and called `(a, b)`.

On the other hand, `{ a, b -> 42 }` is a lambda that takes two parameters, `a` and `b`.

By the way, it's not quite right to name your parameter "lambda" in `fun foo(arg1: Int, arg2: String, lambda: (String, Int) -> Int)`. A lambda is a function-typed syntactic literal, in the same way that `"hello"` is a String literal. But a String parameter is not usually declared as "stringLiteral" because you might not pass a literal but a string variable, or a function call that returns a string. Similarly, you shouldn't name your function-typed parameters "lambda" because you might pass an anonymous function, a method reference, or some other function-typed expression, not necessarily a lambda. Function-type arguments are typically called "block", as you might find in Kotlin stdlib functions such as `let`.